# Format price with commission giving error on Stripe using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm trying to charge customers and then split the payment between myself and the owner who owns the product. The problem Im running into is if the owner of the product, (in this case some file uploads) inserts a value like 99.99 for their price, then someone tries to go checkout, once they enter their Stripe credit card information, they get this error:

[image]

In that case, the price of the product was $99.99.

Here is where I make the charge:

```
 try {
     $charge = Charge::create([
    'amount' => $file->price * 100,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'source' => $request->stripeToken,
    'application_fee' => $file->calculateCommission() * 100
 ], [
    'stripe_account' => $file->user->stripe_id
 ]);
```

And here is the calculateCommission method on the File Model:

```
public function calculateCommission() {
    return (config('marketplace.sales.commission') / 100) * $this->price;
}
```

config('marketplace.sales.commission') in this case is just 20 (20%)

If a user enters a price of lets say 100 ($100), then that charge succeeds

How do I process this commission fee with decimal formats? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's expecting an integer but you're passing a decimal. Stripe works in cents.

Comment: try this 'application_fee' => (double) ($file->calculateCommission() * 100)

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi Partially correct, however this will give `1999.8` which will still throw the error of it being invalid. I would suggest using `floor($file->calculateCommission() * 100)`

Comment: Ok, Ill try this once I get my other bug fixed, cant even get to this part now

Comment: If this is a commercial application, you may want to look into how you handle fraction of cents. This could matter in specific use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @spencdev, it seems like **floor** does the trick. I have tested it with:

```
99.99, .87, 1219.77, 3.00, 10.01, 100.00
```

All work and go through to Stripe

```
floor($file->calculateCommission() * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly format the application fee in your case this goes to 1999.8 . while application fee should be an integer. You can add round off logic to application fee and it will work.

> application_fee (CONNECT ONLY optional):   A fee in cents that will be
>   applied to the charge and transferred to the application owner's
>   Stripe account. To use an application fee, the request must be made on
>   behalf of another account, using the Stripe-Account header, an OAuth
>   key, or the destination parameter. For more information, see the
>   application fees documentation.

In your case, it is not in cents 1999.8 it should be 2000.